# Hide jquery.map errors in google chrome developer tools?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

With the introduction of .map files I am getting my console flooded with errors like:

> Denying load of chrome-extension://flpedblkbobmjlipnnmalidalmhkangn/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Is there any way I can suppress error messages about .map files?

Comment: Just edit `jquery.min.js` and remove `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map`.

Comment: @RobW Not a viable option as you will notice from the error, these are coming from within extensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found) (I realize that this question by Paul Irish was posted later, but it has become a canonical reference for this topic)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### To disable the source maps for one file:

You can filter out the messages for the .map files by right clicking them in the console (Not the link) Selecting `Filter > Hide messages from ...`
[image]

You can also disabled either CSS or JavaScript source maps globally from the Developer Tools settings.

#### To disable the source maps globally:

- Click the cog icon in the bottom right of the Developer Tools
- Locate the 2nd and 3rd options on the right under **Sources**
- Untick Enable JS source maps
- Untick Enable CSS source maps
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Download the map file and place it in the same .js file directory.
http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Although in my case it was coming from an extension, so I couldn't do that.