# Chrome Sending nonsense through ajax via JQuery

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

Alright, I'm using chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m and JQuery 1.9.1.

What I'm doing is using .get to send a short byte command to a microcontroller. However in chrome for some reason a whole lot of other bytes are being sent along with my command.

For instance here is what firefox sends: 255 246 240

Here is what chrome is sending from the same code source: 196 229 164 230 229 134 134 134 163 228 227 229 196 198 135 228 164 135 132 135 132 68 164 132 132 133 164 01 128 103 225 135 132 197 199 230 199 132 68 00 224 228 164 196 229 165 229 35 231 132 164 230 198 231 134 164 230 132 167 196 228 132 135 228 135 227 164 164 134 197 134 228 133 196 133 133 167 102 255 246 240

**edit I was reading that at the wrong baud rate. It is really  giving the byte value for the sentence "GET /JS/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" ("/www/JS/jquery.min.map"): document open: No such file or directory" plus the bytes that it should be sending at the end.

You'll notice that my command is at the end so maybe this is some kind of weird header.

Below is the method that makes this ajax call.

```
    function SendUpdateCommand()
    {
        $.get(
                "/cgi-bin/runcommand.sh?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + ":cmd=254,124,1r10t300",
                {},
                function (responseText) {
                    var response = decodeURI(responseText || "no response text");
                    alert(response);
                    var returnValue = response.split("\n");

                    var bankStatus = returnValue[1].substring(0, returnValue[1].length-1);

                    var val = Number(bankStatus);

                    UpdateBankStatus(val);
                },
                "html"
        );
    }
```

This wouldn't be a problem but my microcontroller reads these as invalid commands and returns around ten zeros. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Firefox request Headers:

```
GET /cgi-bin/runcommand.sh?401:cmd=254,124,1r10t300 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.25
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://192.168.2.25/test.html
Connection: keep-alive
```

Chrome Request Headers:

```
GET /cgi-bin/runcommand.sh?375:cmd=254,124,1r10t300 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.25
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.2.25/test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Firefox Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Nov 1999 00:05:11 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Chrome Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Nov 1999 00:00:10 GMT
Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-type: text/plain
```

**Edit**

I think this is the packet that is causing the problem:

```
GET /JS/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.2.25

Connection: keep-alive

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8



HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Date: Tue, 30 Nov 1999 19:10:14 GMT

Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1



<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>404 Not Found</H1>
The requested URL /JS/jquery.min.map was not found on this server.
</BODY></HTML>
```

This is the packet from my actual command:

```
GET /cgi-bin/runcommand.sh?241:cmd=170,3,254,124,1,40r4t300 HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.2.25

Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

Referer: http://192.168.2.25/test.html

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8



HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Tue, 30 Nov 1999 19:10:15 GMT

Server: Boa/0.94.14rc21

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Connection: close

Content-type: text/plain

OK
170,11,0,0,
```

Somehow these two packets are getting in each others way and maybe being combined on the back end? I'm not sure. Its on a boa server so I'm not sure what all I can do about error checking of the packets.

I fixed the problem by going back to jquery 1.8.

Comment: your URL parameters don't look correct. Try `"/cgi-bin/runcommand.sh?random=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + "&cmd=254,124,1r10t300"`

Comment: No, that's part of the api for my gateway. We extract the random number on the back end

Comment: how are you determining what firefox/chrome "sends" (the grouping of numbers)?

Comment: I have the ethernet module hooked up to a device that reads what it sends out of the UART, which is basically what is sent to that gateway. in the cmd= part. ** the ethernet module has the web server in it.

Comment: Rob has a good question. How does your `runcommand.sh` program "extract" the "back end" of the data? That's where the answer to this question lies, IMO.

Comment: Are you sure it's not printing out part of the request body? FireFox doesn't even seem to be printing out the sent values anyway, right?

Comment: it splits the query string by delimiters and keeps the part after the first :

Comment: can you use both chrome and firefox and provide the entire GET request for each? You can use FireBug and Chrome developer tools to view each of the GET requests.

Comment: I created a fiddle with some test code and ran it with both Chrome and FireFox. If the web server you're using is in fact only checking the params, they should both be the same. http://jsfiddle.net/z57ud/

Comment: I edited the original question to show the GET request headers. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Ok so i was reading it at the incorrect baud rate *Doh!* what the extra bytes actually say is "192.168.2.8 - - [30/Nov/1999:00:03:47 +0000] request "GET /JS/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" ("/www/JS/jquery.min.map"): document open: No such file or directory 254 124 1"

Comment: Without knowing what the server is doing it's hard to figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: The server extracts the random number, uses the cmd=254,124,1 as the command to send out of the serial port. the r10 to say that it will read ten bytes back. and t300 to say that it will wait 300 milliseconds to read the bytes that it receives back over the serial port. I have no idea why it is sending  the jquery.min.map error out over the UART as that file is neither referenced in the front end or anywhere in the backend. I'm not really even sure what it is.

Comment: Seems like it might just be a JQuery bug.

Comment: @Poodimizer, Doubtful.

Comment: @Brad I don't know why else it would be sending the message "GET /JS/jquery.min.map HTTP/1.1" ("/www/JS/jquery.min.map"): document open: No such file or directory". I looked through the jquery-1.9.1.min.js file and saw this line //@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map does anyone know what this is? Am I supposed to have a .min.map file in the same directory as my .min.js?

Comment: @Poodimizer, No, the minified jQuery is fine.  Do a packet capture and post that.  Otherwise, it's a bit difficult to help you.

Comment: @Brad I posted the packets that I think are causing the problem. It seems that somehow the 404 for jquery.min.map is interfering with my runcommand get request.

Comment: refernce: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: So maybe when I first use jQuery it pulls up the file, tries to find the map file and since it can't returns a 404. The boa server, being less than robust somehow ties this packet and my command packet together because they are loosely related thanks to jQuery calling both of them and thus trash data is attached to my runcommand.sh script. That's my theory anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That JS Error you are getting in chrome is due to its support of JS source maps. You could try either downloading the source map so you do not get a 404 or disabling source maps in chrome.

A link to the jQuery 1.9.1 source map is here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.map

To disable see [Hide jquery.map errors in google chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849006/hide-jquery-map-errors-in-google-chrome-developer-tools)